# How to set SolR parameters in POST

Tags: php, solr

I had a problem with Solr select query. Could you help me ?

I would like to transform this GET Method query in POST Method :

```
http://localhost:8983/solr/french_2/select/?q=**&facet.field=field001&facet.field=field002&fq=(website_id:"1") AND (product_status:"1")&sort=field001 asc
```

Here my new query. The first part works fine. The problem is when I try to set facet.field, facet.range, stats.field parameters.

```
http://localhost:8983/solr/french_2/select
$postFields['q'] = '**';
$postFields['fq'] = '(website_id:"1") AND (product_status:"1") AND (instock_int:"1") AND (filter_visibility_int:"3" OR filter_visibility_int:"4") AND (category_id:"203" OR category_id:"203")';
$postFields['sort'] = '203_position_decimal asc';
```

```
$sh = curl_init($url);

    curl_setopt($sh, CURLOPT_HEADER, 0);
    if(is_array($postFields)) {
        curl_setopt($sh, CURLOPT_POST, true);
        curl_setopt($sh, CURLOPT_POSTFIELDS, $postFields);
    }
    curl_setopt($sh, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, 1);

    curl_setopt( $sh, CURLOPT_FOLLOWLOCATION, true );
    if ($type == 'json') {
        curl_setopt( $sh, CURLOPT_HEADER, true );
    }

    if (isset($_GET['user_agent']) || isset($_SERVER['HTTP_USER_AGENT'])) {
        curl_setopt( $sh, CURLOPT_USERAGENT, isset($_GET['user_agent']) ? $_GET['user_agent'] : $_SERVER['HTTP_USER_AGENT'] );
    }

    $this->setupSolrAuthenticate($sh);

    if ($type == 'json') {
        list( $header, $contents ) = @preg_split( '/([\r\n][\r\n])\\1/', curl_exec($sh), 2 );
        $output = preg_split( '/[\r\n]+/', $contents );
    }else{
        $output = curl_exec($sh);
        $output = json_decode($output,true);
    }

    curl_close($sh);
    return $output;
```

How can I set facet.field = "field001,field002" or something like this ?

Thank you very much.

Answer (score 0):

What is the problem that you are facing?

You will have to set:

facet=on

facet.field=field001

facet.field=field002